# Nohup with shell variables before command

Tags: bash, nohup

It seems that `nohup` is unable to run commands that have environment variables before them. For example,

```
nohup LD_PRELOAD=~/file.so ./run &
```

says

```
nohup: failed to run command 'LD_PRELOAD=/home/mahmood/file.so': No such file or directory
```

In fact, `file.so` exists but it is not a command. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting a variable like this

```
foo=bar whatever
```

is a part of shell syntax. The assignment must be before the command.

In your case the shell does not recognize `LD_PRELOAD=~/file.so` as an assignment. It's just an argument to `nohup` and `nohup` does not support setting variables like this.

If you're in a shell (and you most likely are because `~/` and `&` also need a shell) then you can put the variable in the environment of `nohup`, it will be inherited:

```
foo=bar nohup whatever &
```

But this may obviously affect `nohup` itself. If you're not in a shell and/or you don't want the variable to be in the environment of `nohup`, tell `nohup` to run a shell that will interpret the syntax:

```
nohup sh -c 'foo=bar exec whatever'
```

Here I explicitly used `exec` because after the assignment we don't need the shell anymore. I believe some shells exec to the very last command implicitly (at least in some circumstances), some may not.

Comment: But `foo=bar nohup whatever &` doesn't work. If that variable is loaded, the runtime should be large. But I see quick execution which is true when I don't load that variable.

Comment: @mahmood Interesting. In my tests `foo=bar nohup env &` makes `foo=bar` appear in `nohup.out`. This means the variable should get to the environment of `whatever`. I will test further.

Comment: @mahmood My answer stands. I overrode `rand()` by following [this post](https://jvns.ca/blog/2014/11/27/ld-preload-is-super-fun-and-easy/). Then I created a program that calls `srand(time(0))` and prints what`rand()` returns. Sole `./myprogram` gives me a random number. I confirmed that `LD_PRELOAD=./unrandom.so nohup ./myprogram &` appends the fixed value of `42` to `nohup.out`. My testbed is Debian 9.

Comment: OK thanks. The `sh -c` worked for me.